# Merge two dictionaries of data frames based on dictionary keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries of data frames, for each key, I would like to merge the data frames based on a common column. So I thought about creating a dictionary and merging the data frames in a loop, here's an example of my code:

```
Total_data_dict={}
for (keys1,keys2) in zip(dict_1.keys(),dict_2.keys()):
     Total_data_dict["Total_%s" %keys1]=pd.merge(dict_1[keys1],dict_2[keys2], on=['Name'], how='inner')
```

I want the new dictionary to have the merged outcome of the two dictionaries so for example:
the data frame of the first key of dict_1 would be merged with the data frame of the first key of dict_2, and so on.
The problem is: I'm not having the same outcome if I merge them manually outside of the loop. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Provide some data  (input, output) to give readers a better idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure python to achieve that. if you have the same key in both the dictionary, the value of the on the 2nd dictionary is the accepted value if merge

> dict_1 --> dict_2

and visa versa the value of dict_1 will be accepted if merged

> dict_2 --> dict_1

Example

```
some_dict = {1:"some_value", 2:"somevalue2"}
some_dict2 = {1:"no_value", 2:"somevalue2", 3:"somevalue3"}
result = {** some_dict, ** some_dict2} # merge dict 1 with dict 2 

print(result)
{1:'no_value', 2:'somevalue2', 3:'somevalue3'}
```